# Compiling library version into .so file

Tags: c, gcc, versioning, shared-libraries

I have a C linux API library that I distribute both to end users and to servers. When a user needs to use this library, they compile and build a .so file that they send to our servers to be run. I would like a way to compile in the version number of the library into their .so file such that my server can check what version they compiled on. This way if the server is incompatible with the user's .so file, I can refuse to load the library. I'm not sure what options I even have to achieve this and was hoping for any type of suggestion. Please let me know if any more information would be helpful in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common for libraries to have a `getLibraryVersion` function that returns some constant value, be it a string, integer, or whatever. This would get you the version you linked against (i.e. your `.so` version). You could have an additional macro to get the version you compiled against (i.e. your server's version).

For example, SDL's API has a version struct and the following function defined in one of its headers:

```
#define SDL_MAJOR_VERSION   1
#define SDL_MINOR_VERSION   2
#define SDL_PATCHLEVEL      15

typedef struct SDL_version {
    Uint8 major;
    Uint8 minor;
    Uint8 patch;
} SDL_version;

/**
 * This macro can be used to fill a version structure with the compile-time
 * version of the SDL library.
 */
#define SDL_VERSION(X)              \
{                                   \
    (X)->major = SDL_MAJOR_VERSION; \
    (X)->minor = SDL_MINOR_VERSION; \
    (X)->patch = SDL_PATCHLEVEL;    \
}

/**
 * Use this function to get the version of SDL that is linked against
 * your program.
 */
extern void SDL_GetVersion(SDL_version* ver);
```

In one of your `.so`'s `.c` files:

```
void SDL_GetVersion(SDL_version* ver)
{
    SDL_VERSION(ver);
}
```

Example use:

```
SDL_version compiled;
SDL_version linked;

SDL_VERSION(&compiled);
SDL_GetVersion(&linked);

printf("We compiled against SDL version %d.%d.%d ...\n",
   compiled.major, compiled.minor, compiled.patch);
printf("We are linking against SDL version %d.%d.%d.\n",
       linked.major, linked.minor, linked.patch);
```

On a side note; it's a little dangerous to be running somebody else's code on your servers.

Comment: I agree, we do use some linux jailing and are looking into containers and other possible options.  But if the library has that function, how would that get filtered down into the users code? When my server calls getLibraryVersion it would just check its own version on the server and not the version that the .so was compiled against? or am i not understanding

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. I'm not entirely sure how you're using the .so that is delivered to your server, so you may need to elaborate more that, if this doesn't work for you :)

Comment: I'm taking a look at your code now, thank you so much for the help thus far.